# Время выполнение JS скрипта

Tags: javascript

Вот допустим у меня есть скрипт такого типа:

```
<script src="http://script.com/file.js"></script>
```

Мне нужно что бы он работал, к примеру, 3 секунды. Как поставить временное ограничение?

Comment: Вы должны поставить ограничение в самом скрипте, в html, насколько мне известно, такого нет.

Comment: Любой скрипт нельзя запустить на определенное время. Но можно ограничить по времени циклы в скрипте, например. Все зависит от кода скрипта.

Comment: Расскажите для чего это нужно

Comment: Ну вообще, этот скрипт отправляет запросы к различным сайтам, мне нужно ограничить его работу по времени

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй WebWorker.

Например, на сайте [Regex Golf](https://regex.alf.nu/) таким образом ограничивается время проверки корректности регулярного выражения.

Answer (score 1):

Ставим `SetTimeout` и в нем меняем глобальную переменную. А в цикле отслеживаем изменение глобальной переменной.

Но так неправильно. `JavaScript` не так работает (нужно смотреть в сторону асинхронности, `events` и т.п.)

Comment: Эм.. Зачем писать ответом то, что не работает?

Comment: Будет работать. На SetTimeout  ставим изменение переменной, а в нашем долгоиграющем скрипте постоянно проверяем значение переменной. Только это некрасиво.

Comment: Не будет. Или приведи пример.